# Using ListView in inner fragment class

Tags: android, listview, firebase, fragment, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to set an arrayadapter to listview from firebase, but it's not working. I'm using a fragment and it's telling me that "v" AKA my view is accessed from within inner class and needs to be declared final. I have already tried putting "final" in the beginning of the line, but it's not working. I'm very new to Android Studio, so thank you for your help!

This is my code:

```
public class Mandag extends Fragment {

private ListView listView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(mandag, container, false);


    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Skular");

    final SharedPreferences skuule = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("skule", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String Skule = skuule.getString("skule", "");

    final SharedPreferences klaasse = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("klasse", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String Klasse = klaasse.getString("klasse", "");




    myRef.child(Skule).child(Klasse).child("Fag").child("Mandag").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            final List<String> timar = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (DataSnapshot areaSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String skuleName = areaSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                timar.add(skuleName);
            }

            ArrayAdapter<String> skularAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.activity_list_item, timar);

            final ListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.mList);
            listView.setAdapter(skularAdapter);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });

    return v;
}
```

My database:

```
{"Skular" : {
"Kvåle_Skule" : {
  "9A" : {
    "Fag" : {
      "Mandag" : {
        "Fag1" : "Engelsk",
        "Fag2" : "Engelsk",
        "Fag3" : "Matte",
        "Fag4" : "Kosetime:)",
        "Fag5" : "KRLE",
        "Fag6" : "Naturfag"
      }
    },
    "Lekser" : {
      "Naturfag" : "Les side 31 - 34!",
      "Norsk" : "Gjer nåke",
      "Samfunsfag" : "Sjå Ein Debatt 8 ganger"
    }
  },
  "9B" : {
    "Fag" : {
      "Mandag" : {
        "Fag1" : "Norsk",
        "Fag2" : "Norsk",
        "Fag3" : "Matte",
        "Fag4" : "Matte",
        "Fag5" : "Gym",
        "Fag6" : "Gym"
      }
    },
    "Lekser" : {
      "Naturfag" : "Les side 31 - 34!",
      "Norsk" : "Gjer nåke",
      "Samfunsfag" : "Sjå Ein Debatt 2 ganger"
    }
  },
  "9C" : {
    "Fag" : {
      "Mandag" : {
        "Fag1" : "Norsk",
        "Fag2" : "Engelsk",
        "Fag3" : "Matte",
        "Fag4" : "Samfunsfag",
        "Fag5" : "KRLE",
        "Fag6" : "Naturfag"
      }
    },
    "Lekser" : {
      "Naturfag" : "Les side 31 - 34!",
      "Norsk" : "Gjer nåke",
      "Samfunsfag" : "Sjå Ein Debatt"
    }
  },
  "Picker1" : [ "8", "9", "10" ],
  "Picker2" : [ "A", "B", "C" ]

},
},}
```

Thank you if you can help!

EDIT:
My ERROR:

```
    10-02 21:45:05.714 5935-5935/com.heli.minvekeplan E/ArrayAdapter: You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
10-02 21:45:05.714 5935-5935/com.heli.minvekeplan D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
 10-02 21:45:05.717 5935-5935/com.heli.minvekeplan E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                Process: com.heli.minvekeplan, PID: 5935
                                                                java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
                                                                    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
                                                                    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347)
                                                                    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270)
                                                                    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182)
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
                                                                    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1629)
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728)
                                                                    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464)
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139)
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436)
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722)
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613)
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536)
                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2618)
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2019)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1177)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1383)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1065)
                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5901)
                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550)
                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
                                                                    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
                                                                    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362) 
                                                                    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2347) 
                                                                    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1270) 
                                                                    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1182) 
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637) 
                                                                    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728) 
                                                                    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464) 
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637) 
                                                                    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1629) 
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637) 
                                                                    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:728) 
                                                                    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:464) 
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637) 
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536) 
                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436) 
                                                                    at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:139) 
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637) 
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536) 
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436) 
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722) 
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613) 
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637) 
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536) 
                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436) 
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637) 
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536) 
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1436) 
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:722) 
                                                                    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:613) 
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637) 
                                                                    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5536) 
                                                                    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:436) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2618) 
                                                                    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:17637) 
                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2019) 
                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1177) 
                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1383) 
                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1065) 
                                                                    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5901) 
                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767) 
                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580) 
                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:550) 
                                                                    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020) 
                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)
```

Comment: you can avoid having to use `findViewById()` by using butterknife: http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace of the Exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the variable `v` inside an anonymous class in the line

```
final ListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.mList);
```

Also I don't see the name of your `ListView` variable, it should be like:

```
final ListView listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.mList);
```

Move that line outside the anonymous class, for example below this line:

```
String Klasse = klaasse.getString("klasse", "");
```

And leave it final like you have it or you can make your `View` final as follows:

```
final View v = inflater.inflate(mandag, container, false);
```

Comment: There is no layout inflated by the OP. Shouldn't it be something in this line `inflater.inflate(R.layout.mandag, container, false);`

Comment: Thank you for your help, but it is still not working. You can see my error in the updated question.

Comment: @KjellOve Ok the thing is that the layout you are passing is a LinearLayout instead of a TextView that is what the ArrayAdapter expects, you can fix it by changing `android.R.layout.activity_list_item` with `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`.

Comment: @Eury Pérez Beltré Thank you for all your help! Now it finnaly worked! :)